# How to use a pre-built theme on the stand alone Login page of Clerk (when using <ClerkProvider>) on Next.js app?

Tags: next.js, clerk

I am following the Clerk and Next.js quickstart guide on how to set up authentication [here](https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs). *(I am always impressed by Clerk's DX btw.)*

Clerk shows how to apply a pre-built theme [here](https://clerk.com/docs/components/customization/overview#using-a-pre-built-theme) by passing it to the `ClerkProvider`.

```
// /app/layout.js
<ClerkProvider
  appearance={{
  baseTheme: dark,
  signIn: { baseTheme: neobrutalism },
  }}>
    <html lang='en'> 
       ...
    </html>
</ClerkProvider>
```

The base theme changes do seem to take and apply to places like account management etc, but they do not affect the stand alone sign-in page.

I am attempting to get a visual result like [this](https://clerk.com/docs/components/customization/themes#shades-of-purple-theme) but for the stand alone sign-in page (or at least for the sign-in `div` ):

^  After first just changing the overall `baseTheme: dark` and seeing that it did not change the stand alone sign-in page, I added the second `signIn` prop.  I restarted my localhost and signed in and out a few times to check.

---

`Question` Is there another place to change this to apply a `baseTheme` to the stand alone sign-in page?

---

Further context, I see these (separate) [instructions](https://clerk.com/docs/components/authentication/sign-in) on how to add a sign-in component, but these are separate from the above tutorial and I don't fully see how they relate to one another.

My current thinking is that you need the above if you use a `<SignIn />` component as a pop-up on on one of your own pages.

Since, I didn't need to separately add/use this separate component to get the full auth running in the first tutorial, it doesn't seem like this is relevant.  But for good measure, I did add the following code to my app, as specified in the docs, but it didn't affect the stand alone sign-in page.

These changes look like this:

```
// /app/sign-in/[[...sign-in]
import { SignIn } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import { dark } from '@clerk/themes';

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <SignIn
            appearance={{
                baseTheme: dark,
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

---

Btw, sometimes the baseTheme property assignment is done by array or by single prop.  Is one way preferred, or can both simply be handled and are both fine?

Example with array - notice, an array for even one element array under the `baseTheme` prop under the `signIn` component:

```
<ClerkProvider
  appearance={{
    baseTheme: [dark, neobrutalism],
    variables: { colorPrimary: 'red' },
    signIn: { 
      baseTheme: [shadesOfPurple], 
      variables: { colorPrimary: 'blue' }
    }
  }}
>
```

vs. like this with a single prop:

```
<ClerkProvider
  appearance={{
    baseTheme: dark
  }}
>
```